# Use of possessive apostrophe in a list and order of words

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

I would like to know what Lucy, Mary and a third person  think - taking into account they might have different opinions.
Would the following sentence be correct?

*I would like to know Lucy's, Mary's and your thoughts on this issue.*

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to phrase it that way, then yes, you would use an apostrophe with each name because person has his or her own opinion.

If their collective opinion, you would not use an apostrophe, though reordering would probably be necessary for ease of reading: "I would like to know your, Lucy, and Mary's thoughts on this issue." The use of "your" makes it a bit awkward, but the principle is the same as, for example, saying "mom and dad's house" instead of "mom's and dad's house" when you're talking about a home shared by the two.

Answer (score 0):

It might be much tidier to avoid using apostrophes entirely by saying:

*On this issue I would like to know the thoughts of Lucy, Mary and yourself.*

Comment: OP isn't asking for a way to circumvent the syntactic issue - he's specifically asking whether the "possessive" attribute can be *assumed* rather than being explicitly articulated, for all except the last item in a list context.

Comment: Fair enough, but I would like to know the thoughts of the OP on this issue.